# ImportError: cannot import name widgets from django.contrib.admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, newrelic

I'm getting the following inexplicable error all of a sudden:

```
Django Version: 1.4.5
Python Version: 2.7.3

Traceback:
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.18.1.15/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py" in wrapper
  518.             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/webapp/myApp/cmap/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from django.contrib import admin
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in <module>
  4. from django.contrib.admin.options import ModelAdmin, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in <module>
  8. from django.contrib.admin import widgets, helpers

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name widgets
```

I can successfully import widgets (`from django.contrib.admin import widgets`) using the Django shell and a python shell, but it doesn't work when I run my web app.

The command I'm using to launch the app is:

```
newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py run_gunicorn ...
```

I have gone back through my recent commits and don't see anything that could be related to this error.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what is actually in your app, it's difficult to say for certain what happened. However, in the past, when I have encountered similar `ImportError`s, the most common causes were:

- Circular imports (a imports b, b imports c, ..., z imports a)
- Couldn't find module (improperly set up `PYTHONPATH`)
- Missing dependency (forgot to `pip install ...`)

Answer (score 0):

I see the following line in the traceback -

```
File "/home/webapp/myApp/cmap/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from django.contrib import admin
File "/home/webapp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in <module>
```

Seems like a circular import issue , do you really need that import in that file?

Comment: It's required in that file to enable admin functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked this down to the commit that caused the problem. I had added this to my logging configuration in settings.py:

```
'loggers' : {
    '': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['logfile','sentry'], 
        'propagate': False,
```

...thinking that I was adding a default logger. This led to a string of inexplicable errors, including the one I posted here. Removing it fixed everything.

Note that Ming's answer is the best general purpose answer to this error.